# Why api response body is not showing in postman app generated documentation?

Tags: api, postman, api-doc

I am testing `apis` usng `postman` continuously and then generating  **api documentation** using `postman` app.

But problem is that documentation is not displaying `api response` which i am receiving in `postman console`. Here is the response which i am receiving for most of my `apis`

[image]

How can i get response body also in my api documentation?

Comment: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/mocking-with-examples/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the request has been saved to a collection, You can use the `Save as example` feature, found to the top right of the response body. This will open the `example` builder and once saved, this response body will be shown against the request on your API documentation.

[image]

More details of how that works can be found here:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/examples/#how-your-examples-appear-in-postman-documentation

Comment: I saved about three response examples in my request but only one (the first one) is showing up in the documentation. Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Do you want to open separate questions with all the details? It's how to know when you mean without seeing some images of the app/dashboard.

Comment: @TaslimOseni did you get answer for showing multiple responses in documentation ?

Comment: Hi @Thanthu, check [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/examples/) out. I'm sure it'd be helpful.

Comment: @TaslimOseni Thanks, I just missed the dropdown that was shown in the doc to switch examples.

Comment: Glad I could help.